# Move uiview once uilabel text has changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIlabel that when a user clicks a button its text changes, this label is then resized using:

```
CGRect frame = label.frame;
    [label sizeToFit];
    frame.size.height = label.frame.size.height;
    label.frame = frame;
```

So that the width is kept the same but the height of the label is changed so all text fits in this.

I then however need the uiview below this label to be moved down so that it starts at the bottom of the label, how do I do this?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Can you not just change the frame or constraint and adjust the position of the frame at the same time or immediately after the label is resized?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out in the end by doing:

```
    CGRect contentframe = _lbl_content.frame; //the uilabel
    CGRect keyframe = _view_keystuff.frame; //the uiview
    float startlocation = contentframe.origin.y;
    startlocation += contentframe.size.height;
    keyframe.origin.y = startlocation;
    _view_keystuff.frame = keyframe;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to put the UIView below the label?

Try this:

```
UIView *viewBelowLabel = [[UIView alloc] init];

viewBelowLabel.frame = CGRectMake( "your view origin x", label.frame.origin.y + label.frame.size.height, "your view size width", "your view size height");
```

You should adjust UIView frame after the resizing of the label